# «Но я не знаю как». Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Нужны ли запятые во втором предложении: после **но** и перед **как**?

**В теории это можно сделать. Но я не знаю как.**

Comment: Хотелось бы знать, из каких соображений вы предполагаете наличие запятой перед Я.

Answer (score 1):

*В теории это можно сделать. **Но я не знаю как.***

**I.** В словаре Ефремовой:
[**НО**](http://%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%84/%D0%BD%D0%BE)
3. Союз. 3) Употребляется при противопоставлении одного предложения другому или ряду 
предложений, находясь в начале предложения и отграничивая то, что высказано 
ранее.

Знаков препинания не требует.

**II.** **Как** в этом предложении выступает в качестве **наречия.** Его спокойно можно заменить выражением ***каким образом*** — в этом случае выделять **как** запятой не нужно.

[Проблемы КАК](http://www.rusyaz.ru/is/kak.html)

Чтобы усилить значение "как" в предложении, можно придать ему [предложению] вопросительную интонацию. Тогда возможна постановка тире.
**Но я не знаю — как?**

Answer (score 1):

1) Если придаточное предложение состоит из одного союзного слова, то **в общем случае** запятая не ставится: ***Но я не знаю как.***

***Как*** — это дополнение, не знаю (что?).

2)  Примеры из Розенталя:  Я бы тоже желал знать почему (Л. Т.); Не знаю почему, но я его не понимал (Триф.); Трудно сказать почему; Он ушёл и не сказал куда; Он обещал скоро вернуться, но не уточнил когда;

3) В условиях **контекста** возможна **постановка запятой или тире и перед одиночным союзным словом:** Что же надо делать? Научите, что — усиленное **логическое выделение** местоимения; Одно время он что-то шептал, не могли понять — что? (А. Т.) — постановка тире подчеркивает значение местоимения и оправдывается **вопросительной интонацией.**http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137

4) **Но вот контекста в вопросе практически нет.**

Вернее, он есть, но смысл предложения неясен, поэтому выбрать знак по правилу  Розенталя не представляется возможным.

***В теории это можно сделать. Но я не знаю как.***

Можно это понять так: *Теоретически это можно сделать, но я не знаю, как это сделать практически*. Но в заданном сообщении этот **смысл выражен неясно.**

Если смысл в другом, **то логика неясна.** Можно сделать, но не знаю, как сделать? Тогда откуда известно, что можно сделать.

**И вывод:** Автор должен ясно выражать свои мысли, чтобы читателю не приходилось угадывать содержание. Только в этом случае можно говорить о  правильности постановки знаков препинания.